# Эмулятор андроид для Unity Build and run

Tags: unity3d

Есть несколько эмуляторов, которые успешно обрабатывают apk Unity.
На все них apk надо сохранить и вручную загружать.
Но не получилось найти не один, который работает по команде Build and Run, как просто подключенное android устройство.

Есть ли что то подобное? У nox app player есть интеграция с Android Studio, но с юнити при тех же настройках не работает.

Поделитесь опытом, возможно ли в один клик запускать через эмулятор приложения прям из Unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для бИлда в Юнити и одновременного теста на андройде есть такая штука как [Unity Remote 4](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote4.html).

Unity Remote 4 - это программка, которая помогает осуществить удаленный контроль к проекту в Unity Editor.

Обычно на андройде скачивается это приложение (через google play к примеру),
и также в настройках *Debugging* надо поставить галочку *Аndroid Debugging (enable the Android Debug bridge "adb" intefrace)*.

Надо не забыть подключить телефон к компьютеру (или на чем идет разработка).

При запуске приложения можно будет видеть следующую картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Unity надо переключиться на платформу Android. А также в настройках

`Edit`→`Project Settings`→`Editor` в пункте *Unity Remote* → `Device` выбрать `Any Android Device`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого если нажать *Play* - игра должна запуститься в редакторе и на телефоне тоже

---

Если телефона нет, то данная фишка может прокатить только с эмулятором андройда, установленным через AVD Manager.exe  Причем настройка *CPU/ABI* обязательно должна быть *ARM armeabi*. При значении *Intel x86*  работать не будет.

Примерные настройки для AVD:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После установки эмулятора надо установить Unity Remote 4 из apk в эмулятор используя команду: adb.exe install `adb.exe install path/to/apk` (Windows) или `adb install path/to/apk` (Linux/Mac).

Всё остальное как и при работе с телефоном - сделать настройки в Unity и прочее. После всех установок желательно перезагрузить Unity!

Comment: В том и постановка вопроса, что нужен эмулятор.У телефона разъем usb жалко всё время туда-сюда дёргать. 
А вот через AVD попробую, спасибо. Просто он не очень быстр, есть альтернативы которые работают для Unity?

Comment: @Dmitrii `У телефона разъем usb жалко всё время туда-сюда дёргать.` - зачем его туда-сюда дергать? достаточно один раз подключить и работать. А вынимать шнур только после того, как закончили работать......... еще альтернативы пока не наблюдал. ибо лучшие эмуляторы nox и blue stacks, однако они что-то не хотят работать через remote вообще никак........ поэтому если есть телефон, лучше уж через него. Остальное - только мучение

Comment: @Dmitrii добавил скрин для AVD. Должен работать. Но AVD - слишком глючный конечно.